# Url.Action: How to Pass Parameter from View to Controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I'm having issues with passing a parameter from my View to Controller using Url.Action.

My code is the following in the View:

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="search_criteria" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<div id="SearchDiv">

</div>
```

In my Script:

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index_AddSearchCriteria", "Home", "search_criteria")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#SearchDiv').html(result);
        }
    })
})
```

In the Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Index_AddSearchCriteria(string search_criteria)
        {
            ViewModel.SearchCriteria = search_criteria;

            return PartialView("SearchBar", ViewModel);
        }
```

How would I send a parameter through Url.Action so that it may be accepted as a parameter in the Controller?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `data:` parameter

```
var data = { search_criteria: $("search_criteria).val() }; // add id="search_criteria" to the textbox
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Index_AddSearchCriteria", "Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#SearchDiv').html(result);
    }
})
```

or you could simplify it to

```
$('#SearchDiv').load('@Url.Action("Index_AddSearchCriteria", "Home")', { search_criteria: $("search_criteria).val() });
```