# json being returned via url but not via jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I'm using Visual Studio to develop an MVC app and I have a jquery function that seems to be causing problems. I developed an action method that returns a json object (jquery calls action > action calls a service > the service returns an object > action converts object to a model via a map then passes the model to json). The action can be called via url (passing an id parameter via the query string) and it returns the json to the web page, however, when I call the jquery function via the web page (click on a button that executes the jquery), I get a "localhost:50216 says an error has occurred" before the rest of the jquery function executes. Been researching this for several days and tried using Chrome's debugger to no avail. Hopefully this makes sense, but if I need to provide further information please let me know. Any insight would be much appreciated.
Best,
Jon

```
$("#delayEditModal")
    .on("show.bs.modal",
        function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var delId = button.data("guid");
            var name = button.data("name");
            var modal = $(this);
            $.get("@Url.Action("GetDelayDataForEditing", "TrainActivity")", function(data){
                alert("Data: " + data);
            });
            modal.find(".modal-body").text("Edit the Delay at " + name + " with id " + delId);
            modal.find(".modal-footer #delayEditButton").data("guid", delId);
    });
```

I'm able to get to the popup (when I click on the button that has the id=#delayEditModal) that displays "Edit the Delay at...", however before that - I believe when the $.get method executes - I get the 500 error. Also, I never hit the alert("Data: "..) portion.

So I've looked at a couple articles (one of them [Url.Action: How to Pass Parameter from View to Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746544/url-action-how-to-pass-parameter-from-view-to-controller)) andmade some changes to my code. Still no success. Will continue to research solutions.

```
$("#delayEditModal")
    .on("show.bs.modal",
        function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var delId = button.data("guid");
            var name = button.data("name");
            var modal = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetDelayDataForEditing")/" + delId,
                //data: delId,
                success: function () {
                    alert("Success");
                    //$('#delays-grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                    //$("#delayAddModal").modal("hide");
                },
                error: function () { alert("error"); }
            });
            //modal.find(".modal-body").text("Edit the Delay at " + name + " with id " + delId);
            modal.find(".modal-footer #delayEditButton").data("guid", delId);
    });
```

Edit: I don't think I'm even hitting my ActionResult method. I'v set a break point there and don't ever hit it.

Edit: I'm finally able to reach "Success":

```
$("#delayEditModal")
        .on("show.bs.modal",
        function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
                var delId = button.data("guid");
                var name = button.data("name");
            var modal = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetDelayDataForEditing")/" + "?delayId=" + delId,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    //data: delId,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success" + data);
                        //$('#delays-grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                        //$("#delayAddModal").modal("hide");
                    },
                    error: function () { alert("error"); }
                });
                modal.find(".modal-body").text("Edit the Delay at " + name + " with id " + delId);
                modal.find(".modal-footer #delayEditButton").data("guid", delId);
        });
```

However, I'd like to figure out how to display the raw contents of the json object in the modal. This will have to be a task for Monday. Many thanks to all for sharing your advice and insight. Have a great weekend!

Comment: @Taplar sorry I forgot to include the code... been a long week.

Comment: if you're getting a 500 error then it's a server-side error...so you need to check your server's event or exception logs to get details of what went wrong. One thing though - in the question text you mention that "The action can be called via url (passing an id parameter via the query string)"...yet in your $.get call to it you don't provide any such parameter. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your prompt response. I've already checked my localhost server logs and there is nothing there except the generic 500 substatus: 0. Also, your observation about the lack of a parameter is one that I've wondered myself. Sadly, I've been unable to get a straight answer from any of the senior developers here - or if they HAVE given me an answer it's in Greek. SMH.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, so my supervisor finally gave me a straight answer and confirmed my suspicion that the ID was missing from the jquery call to the action. I will have to research how to do that. Thank you for providing the impetus for me to "balls up" and approach my lead about that. :)

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the action method on the server please. Also try looking for errors in the Windows Event Viewer on the server rather than the IIS logs. And make sure your code isn't swallowing exceptions anywhere (e.g. using try-catch blocks which simply ignore the caught exception rather than logging and/or re-throwing it.

Comment: @ADyson I believe I may have solved it. See most recent code block above. My url was not formed properly (missing ?delayId=). At least I'm hitting the alert("Success" + data); statement. Now just trying to figure out how to echo the object data to the modal body.

Comment: That would make sense, if your action method's parameter name is "delayId" rather than "id" - the parameter name you send must match the one the server is expecting to receive. If you simply want to display the raw contents of the JSON in the modal, then choose an element to insert the data into and place a stringified version of it in there - e.g. something like `$("#myDivID").text(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: @ADyson Thank you sir. I was able to display the contents of the object in the alert. Also, How do I mark your original suggestion about the problem with my id, as the answer?

Comment: I have now written a formal answer so you can accept it - thank you. Comments like the above are just discussion points which cannot be marked as answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question text you mention that "The action can be called via url (passing an id parameter via the query string)"...yet in your $.get call to it you don't provide any such parameter.

You need to provide a parameter to the server, with the same name as the one your action method is expecting, for example:

```
url: "@Url.Action("GetDelayDataForEditing")/" + "?delayId=" + delId,
```

The part after the `?` is the parameter name, then the part after the `=` is the value to send for that parameter.